# Swift: Creating a button that calls a method in another class

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I want to create button in a class named "store "and when it is clicked it calls a method named "storeSelected" in another class called ExploreViewController.

```
//class store
//create button
button.addTarget(ExploreViewController(), action: "storeSelected:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


//class ExploreViewController


@IBAction func storeSelected(sender: UIButton) {

  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("pushProductDetail", sender: sender)
}
```

The above code generates an error when clicking the button, Why? How can I solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're making the action on a new instance of `ExploreViewController`, which will get deallocated immediately after the method is called. Store your `ExploreViewController` somewhere or use an existing instance.

Sample code:

`Store` class, assuming button created

```
protocol storeDelegate {
    func storeSelected(sender:UIButton)
}

var delegate: storeDelegate // <-- conforms to the storeDelegate protocol

// somewhere in viewDidLoad?
button.addTarget(delegate, action: "storeSelected:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

`ExploreViewController` class

```
class ExploreViewController: storeDelegate {
    func storeSelected(sender: UIButton) {
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("pushProductDetail", sender: sender)
    }

// somewhere in here where you create the Store class:
    store.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: @OmarKayali I need to know the context: So you have this first vc that presents a second vc, but where's the button and where do you want to call a method?

Comment: I have a vc class named "exploreViewController" and another object class named "store" that creates the button and has the the button.addtarget...   The func storeSelected in in the vc class.

Comment: your `store` class must have a reference back to the `exploreViewController`. What I recommend is you create a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) and let `exploreViewController` conform to the protocol. Then you can simply get the delegate to perform the method like `delegate.pushProductDetail`.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could provide a sample code, this would be clearer for me. Thank you in advance

Comment: button.addTarget(delegate, action:"storeSelected:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) This line of code gives me an error which is 'storeDelegate' is not identical to 'AnyObject'. What is the meaning of this error and how can I solve it? Thank you in advance

Comment: @OmarKayali try casting it to AnyObject (`button.addTarget(delegate as AnyObject, action:"storeSelected:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`)

Answer (score -1):

for Swift 2.2 It Works thanks @Schemetrical.

```
protocol storeDelegate {
    func storeSelected(sender:UIButton)
}
var delegate: storeDelegate! // <-- conforms to the storeDelegate protocol

// somewhere in viewDidLoad?
button.addTarget(delegate as? AnyObject, action: "storeSelected:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```